# Помогите с функцией поиска

Tags: javascript

Пищу PDF-Viewer на React App, нужно чтобы кнопка поиска находила текст который введен в поисковую строку
Она должна искать и выделять его по сути как F3
Вот сам код:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack' // Import PDF.js at the top
import './App.css'

function App() {
    const [pdfURL, setPdfURL] = useState(null)
    const inputTextRef = useRef(null)

    const searchFunction = text => {
        console.log('Search Text:', text) // Check the input text
        const information = document.querySelectorAll('.searchDiv')
        console.log('Elements:', information) // Check the selected elements
        information.forEach(element => {
            if (element.textContent.includes(text)) {
                console.log('Matched Element:', element) // Check matched elements
                element.classList.add('animationElement')
                setTimeout(() => {
                    element.classList.remove('animationElement')
                }, 2000)
            }
        })
    }

    const openPdf = () => {
        const input = document.createElement('input')
        input.type = 'file'
        input.accept = 'application/pdf'

        input.addEventListener('change', async event => {
            const file = event.target.files[0]

            if (file) {
                const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
                setPdfURL(fileURL)
            }
        })

        input.click()
    }

    const searchPdf = async text => {
        if (!pdfURL) {
            alert('Please open a PDF first.')
            return
        }

        try {
            const pdf = await pdfjs.getDocument(pdfURL).promise
            const maxPages = pdf.numPages

            for (let pageNum = 1; pageNum <= maxPages; pageNum++) {
                const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNum)
                const pageText = await page.getTextContent()

                pageText.items.forEach(item => {
                    const itemText = item.str
                    if (itemText.includes(text)) {
                        // Handle the matched text within the PDF, e.g., highlight or alert
                        console.log('Match found on page', pageNum)
                    }
                })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error searching PDF:', error)
        }
    }

    const downloadBasicPdf = () => {
        alert('In development')
    }

    const openBasicPdf = () => {
        alert('In development')
    }

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const searchText = inputTextRef.current.value
        searchFunction(searchText) // Search on the webpage content
        searchPdf(searchText) // Search within the PDF
    }

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <header className='App-header'>
                <h1>PDF View</h1>
                <div className='buttons-container'>
                    <button onClick={openPdf}>Open PDF</button>
                    <button onClick={downloadBasicPdf}>Download Basic PDF</button>
                    <button onClick={openBasicPdf}>Open Basic PDF</button>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <input type='text' ref={inputTextRef} />
                        <input type='submit' value='search' />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </header>
            {pdfURL && (
                <iframe src={pdfURL} title='PDF Viewer' width='100%' height='1250px' />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
export default App
```

```css
@import '@react-pdf-viewer/core/lib/styles/index.css';


.App {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Header styles */
.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.buttons-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

button {
  background-color: #61dafb;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


button:hover {
  background-color: #45aaf2;
}
```